Does this polynomial enumerating subsets of edges of a bipartite graph have a name?
Let $g$ be a bipartite graph with edge set $E$ and partition $A, B$. Define the polynomial $p_g$ by
$$
p_g(x,y) = \sum_{J \subset E} (-1)^{|J|} x^{|V(J)\cap A|} y^{|V(J)\cap B|}
$$
where $V(J)$ is the set of vertices of $g$ that are not incident to some edge of $J$.
Take for example the following graph (unfortunately I have A and B as vertex labels, hopefully it doesn't cause confusion):

The set  $J = \{ B2, \space B3 \}$ produces the term $x^2y$, since the vertices incident to $J$ are $ \{B, 2, 3\}$ and we have $2$ vertices ($A$ and $C$) remaining on the left and one ($1$) on the right.
The whole polynomial is
$$
p_g(x,y) = x^{3} y^{3} - 5 x^{2} y^{2} + 2 x^{2} y + 3 x y^{2} + x y - y^{2} - x
$$
Does this polynomial have a known name or representation?
By the way, I noticed that $p_{h \sqcup g} = p_hp_g$, which follows from convolution formula as any subset of edges of the disjoint union $h \sqcup g$ splits as a disjoint union $J_1 \sqcup J_2$ and then the corresponging terms go just right. (This is perhaps even clearer, if we also put $z^{|J|}$ instead of $(-1)^{|J|}$ and then set $z=-1$ in the end.)
I think, if we introduce that $z$ and only consider the part where degree of all variables agree, might be related to the matching polynomial, since then every edge takes one vertex from each side and no two edges share a vertex.
I stumpled upon this while solving this question.

Looks like some special form of the tutte polynomial. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial
